# Add routes dynamically in angular 2

Tags: typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I want to add path in routes dynamically. Something like that.
I'm getting **EmpURL** form another class. On clicking a specific function **EmpURL** changes its value in this class as well as in 
`this.router.navigate(["/admin:" + emp.empno])`**(admin.component.ts).**
Here emp.empno returns one element i.e. **employee1**,  **employee2** etc.
**EmpURL** also access only one element at a time.
I know I can't do it in this way. I just want to make my point clear.

here's router.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { AdminAccount } from "../admin/admin.component";
import { EmployeeComponent } from "../employee/employee.component";

export const Routing: Routes =
[
    { path: '', component: Home },
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminAccount },
    { path: 'admin:' + this.EmpURL, component: EmployeeComponent }
];
@Component(
{
    selector: "router",
})
export class NaviagteToEmp
{
    @Input() EmpURL;
}
```

here's admin.component.ts

```
navigateTo(emp: EmpLogin)
{
    for(let key in this.data)
        this.EmpURL[key] = this.data[key].empno;
    this.router.navigate(["/admin:" + emp.empno]);

}
```

here's admin.component.html

```
<router [EmpURL] = 'EmpURL.employee1'></router>
```

here accessing one of the element **employee1**.This **employee1** is not static. It will change its value dynamically.

Comment: you may add `admin\:id`, The :id in the route is a token for a route parameter. In a URL such as admin\employee1 etc , which will be changed dynamically. Read more [about routing here](https://angular.io/guide/router), Cheers!!

Comment: @MadhuRanjan Thanks... :)